# Regex Matching Differs from Java & Online Tools

Tags: java, regex

So when I put this regex:

```
\d{3}[\-\.\s]\d{3}[\-\.\s]\d{4}
```

through this website:

http://regexr.com/

it works perfectly! But when I take that same regex and utilize it in Java like so:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{3}[\\-\\.\\s]\\d{3}[\\-\\.]\\d{4}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);
```

it starts matching digits as well like 123.12341234

Any ideas?

Comment: [this](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) site uses java but doesn't match `123.12341234`

Comment: You omitted `\s` in the Java regex version. Moreover, no need escaping that often: `\\d{3}[-.\\s]\\d{3}[-.\\s]\\d{4}`

Comment: A good way of debugging most problems is: break down the code into sections and debug them one by one. For regular expressions, it's the same.

Comment: The site did work correctly, but i'm not sure what the difference could be since it's the same regex... Changing what I escaped didn't work either. My understanding is that "\\d{3}" matches any three digits, and [-.\\s] matches a single occurrence of a dash, dot or space. However, it's matching a digit in my java program.

Comment: So just to try and hone in on the problem I tried this just to try and force it not to match: \\d{3}[-.\\s]\\d{3}\\D{1}\\d{4}  and it still matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, the regex was correct, I was putting it into the incorrect part of the program. Sorry I wasted all of your time! I appreciate the help though.